# Apache Stanbol LDpath program

Tags: apache-stanbol

I'm getting the message

500 Solr Template ZIP cannot be found in:solr/core/\template.zip

When I try to create an LDPath on `http://localhost:8080/contenthub/ldpath`.

What's wrong?

Cheers,
Kamal

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Windows? It looks like a bug composing the path. Please, submit it to the project issue tracker.